# How to do a button that is enable or disabled depending the user?

Tags: php, sql

i need to do an input button that is enabled if you are the admin but to be disabled if you are another user. Can i do that with php ? The userid is 123456789A, Its a select from a database.

```html
<?php

session_start();

$comprobar = "123456789A";
echo $comprobar;
echo $_SESSION['userid'];

if ($comprobar = $_SESSION['userid']) {   
    echo '
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Todos los castigos" id="boton_castigos"
       onClick="location.href="castigos.php""/>
';
}

?>
```

Comment: Just add the `disabled` attribute to the input dependent on user.

Comment: Your `if` condition should have double equals (equality is `==` or `===`, `=` sets the variable), and your `onclick` has enclosed double-quotes, which within the double-quoted attribute value, should be single quotes. Formatting your code well makes these things easier to see. `:)`

Comment: And, y'know, setting `disabled` on an `input` does not _prevent_ someone from still making the request. The security/permission should first be on the server; what's in the browser is for clarity and convenience. Here, it seems like you're trying to use `disabled` to clarify access to that functionality, but the real enforcement should always be on the server by checking if the user can first do what they're requesting to do..

Comment: I tried and that is right, it apeears enable for admin and diabled for user but the onclick doesnt work, i think that is because is in a php echo.

Comment: It's because it should be this: `onClick="location.href=\'castigos.php\'"` Notice the escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code hope it will work, I just added a `disabled` attribute in it but proper why should be like this

```
<?php
 session_start();
$comprobar="123456789A";
echo $comprobar;

echo $_SESSION['userid'];
if ($comprobar=$_SESSION['userid']) {   
 echo "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Todos los castigos' 
    id='boton_castigos' onClick='location.href='castigos.php' disabled />";
} else {
 echo "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Todos los castigos' 
    id='boton_castigos' onClick='location.href='castigos.php'/>";
}
?>
```

Ok. It works. I post it

```html
            <?php   
                                        $comprobar="17466470V";                                                                 

                                            if (!($comprobar==$_SESSION['userid'])) {   
                                             echo "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Todos los castigos' 
                                                id='boton_castigos' onClick='location.href='castigos.php' disabled />";
                                            } else {


                                            echo "<input class='btn' type='button' value='Todos los castigos' 
                                                id='boton_castigos' onClick='location.href=\"castigos.php\"' />";


                                                }
                                            ?>
```

Comment: Yes it appears disabled now but the onlclick doesnt work. In the if ($comprobar=$_SESSION['userid']) is if($comprobar==$_SESSION['userid']). I looked now haha. Thanks for the help